# Multiprocessing pool not working despite memory assignment

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I processed the preprocessing which must be iterative using multiprocessing.

The below code works normally.

```
wt_adherence = partial(get_wt_adherence, wt=wt_logs, user_profile=user_profile)

n_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
result_wt = pool.map(wt_adherence, accessCodes)         ; print('wt adherence finished')
pool.close()
```

The problem occurs when the below code.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
result_meal = pool.map(meals_adherence, accessCodes)     ; print('meal adherence finished')
pool.close()
```

When the second script run, the parallel process showed below in Linux kernel (with top).

Although the memory were assigned to each process (10.8%), the CPUs not working.

```
21934 hoheon    20   0 38.431g 0.035t  29488 S 100.7 14.4  50:22.80 python3                                                                                        
22396 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22397 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22398 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22399 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22400 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22401 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22402 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22403 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3996 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22395 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3984 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3                                                                                        
22404 hoheon    20   0 29.399g 0.027t   3984 S   0.0 10.8   0:00.00 python3
```

I suspected the function named 'meals_adherence' using the pandas dataframe with 1GB size.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 32691788 entries, ('111TN3AT', Timestamp('2018-06-27 00:00:00')) to ('ZZZG24EX', Timestamp('2018-09-24 00:00:00'))
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column       Dtype  
---  ------       -----  
 0   timeSlot     object 
 1   didSkipMeal  int8   
 2   foodType     object 
 3   foodName     object 
 4   calories     float16
dtypes: float16(1), int8(1), object(3)
memory usage: 966.7+ MB
```

however, the memory and CPU process is idle because my PC has the memory capacity of PC 250GB and 50CPUs
Even, 50% of memory space left.

When I wait 3 hours and check the script again, the following error will also appear.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_feature_ext_multiprocessing.py", line 137, in <module>
    result_meal = pool.map(meals_adherence, accessCodes)     ; print('meal adherence finished')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 393, in _send_bytes
    header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

Why do occur this problem?

Comment: Your process virtual memory is almost 30 gig per worker which goes beyond your 250G physical. The error, though, could be with how much data you are passing back to the main process. More than 2gig of data, does that seem like what you'd expect? Perhaps you could pass the return data through the file system.

Comment: Dear, tdelanny. as you mention, I saw the virtual memory almost was almost full using top process.